# Lexical or Preprocessor issue / xmlversion.h not found when using Sudzc/VTK in an iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, vtk, sudzc

I've set up VES and am modifying the Kiwiviewer app in XCode 4.3.2. Kiwi builds and runs fine, so I'm now trying to set up Sudzc within my app (it works fine standalone). I've followed the tutorial [here](http://sudzc.com/Tutorial/ObjC.mov) but at the point after modifying the headers, where his app builds and runs, mine instead comes up with a succession of errors. At first, it gives >150 errors all along the lines of:

```
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue
Invalid token at start of a preprocessor expression
```

Mostly pointing at the line

```
#include "xmlversion.h"
```

in a file tree.h, which is a part of vtkmodular/Utilities/vtklibxml2/include/libxml/tree.h.

Changing the " " to < > (which was suggested for a similar problem) instead gives another Lexical or Preprocessor Issue, this time that 'xmlversion.h' file not found - seemingly all in the file tree.h. The file's in my Project Navigator (and cmd-clicking on #include "xmlversion.h" does indeed load the file, so it understands it that way).

Presumably then the problem is with vtk having its own version of libxml2? If this is the case - what can I do about this? All of the errors I've looked at seem to originate from within soap handler classes, and eventually get through to "include < libxml/tree.h>" - which is then in the vtk directory shown above. I'm not really sure where to go from here - is it wrong to include the library that's added in the instructions? Can/should I modify the header paths? If this isn't the tree.h the rest of the code is looking for, where is it - a quick system search didn't find it?

Or am I completely off the mark?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from the VES Mailing List, link [here](http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/ves/2012-April/000053.html). It ended up being as simple as removing the VTK version of libxml2, which it seems VES doesn't use. Hope this might be of use to someone!